# Line Intersect in Diagonals of a Rectangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The diagonals of the rectangle have these equations: $$y = 4x-10\\ \\ y = -4x+18$$

Find the point at which the diagonals intersect.

---

First, I tried working out $(x,y)$

$4x - 10 = -4x + 18$

$4x = -4x + 28$

$8x = 28$

$x = 3.5$

And then idk...

Thanks guys!

Comment: What equals $28$? notice that $4x \neq -4x$ in general.

Comment: You need to add $ \ 4x \ $ to both sides of the equation to eliminate it on the right-hand side.  After that, you should have $ \ 8x \ = \ 28 \ $ .

Comment: I see what I did there, thanks.

Comment: Except for x = 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$4x=-4x+28 \iff 8x=28 \iff x=3.5$$
$$y=4\cdot 3.5 -10 = 4$$

Answer (score 1):

solve the system of equations:  $$y = 4x-10\\ \\ y = -4x+18$$ you'll get only one point (as expected in a triangle):$(\frac{14}{4},4)$ which also satisfies what was asked.